# Dynamically defined macros for each row in csv file using datatool produces erroneous results

Tags: macros, datatool

Please see the following example. I thought that this would be pretty straightforward. But the processing seems to be delayed (or done in chunks) where erroneous results are being produced.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.csv}
a, A, 100
b, B, 200
c, C, 300
d, D, 400
e, E, 500
f, F, 600
g, G, 700
h, H, 800
i, I, 900
\end{filecontents}


% Load database
\DTLloaddb[noheader]{\jobname}{\jobname.csv}

% Define macros
\DTLforeach{\jobname}{\Tag=Column1, \N=Column2, \V=Column3}{%
  \expandafter\def\csname\Tag\endcsname{\N}
  \expandafter\def\csname\Tag Value\endcsname{\V}}


\begin{enumerate}
\item \b, \bValue               % Should give B, 200
\item \d, \dValue               % D, 400
\item \i, \iValue               % I, 900
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

See the results produced.

[image]

How can I make the processing immediate?

Comment: If you know that your \N and \V values are simple (work in a \edef}, you can use \edef instead of \def. You shouldn't define commands like \b or \i: you are overwriting existing latex commands here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `\edef`, otherwise `\N` and `\V` would print the last value assigned to them.

Anyway, you should be very careful when using `\def`; for instance you're redefining `\a`, `\b` and `\c`, which are important LaTeX commands for typesetting accented letters.

I suggest a different strategy: first do the processing of the database inside a group and use `\xdef` (global expanded definition), but using “internal commands” that you can recover with “external” ones.

```latex
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.csv}
a, A, 100
b, B, 200
c, C, 300
d, D, 400
e, E, 500
f, F, 600
g, G, 700
h, H, 800
i, I, 900
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}

\newcommand{\getrowN}[1]{\csname masroor@row@#1@N\endcsname}
\newcommand{\getrowV}[1]{\csname masroor@row@#1@V\endcsname}

% Load database
\DTLloaddb[noheader]{\jobname}{\jobname.csv}

% Define macros
\begingroup
\DTLforeach{\jobname}{\Tag=Column1, \N=Column2, \V=Column3}{%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname masroor@row@\Tag@N\endcsname{\N}%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname masroor@row@\Tag@V\endcsname{\V}%
}
\endgroup

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \getrowN{b}, \getrowV{b}  % Should give B, 200
\item \getrowN{d}, \getrowV{d}  % D, 400
\item \getrowN{i}, \getrowV{i}  % I, 900
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By using a group, the fact that you're using `\def` for `\Tag`, `\N` or `\V` will not propagate outside the group and if those commands are already defined, they will revert their behavior at `\endgroup`.

It would be different for `\b` or `\c`, because you'd need them in the document. That's the reason for using `\getrowN` and `\getrowV` in order to retrieve the values.

Comment: Thanks. The *usage* part of the macros is already written and is an extensive one. So, to adapt your suggested method, which is an excellent one (as always) we would need a major rework in a large document. I went for writing the definitions in an external style file and using that file after the output stream is closed. It is working fine. I will accept your answer anyway, because as of this moment, this is the only (good) one. 
 *(Those `\a`, `\b`... were only part of a quick MWE, actual usages are very different, but thanks for the word of caution.)*

Answer (score 1):

You almost did it.

But...

**Issue 1:**

The definitions of `\Tag`, `\N` and `\V` will be overridden with each iteration of the `\DTLforeach`-loop.

Therefore these macros need to be expanded with each iteration of the loop.

`\csname` triggers expanding things  (and thus in your example triggers expansion of `\Tag`) until finding the matching `\endcsname`.

But with `\N` and `\V` some extra steps are needed for ensuring not to have the token `\N`/not to have the token `\V` but to have the expansion of the token `\N`/to have the expansion of the token `\V` within the definition-text within each iteration of the loop.

I slightly modified your example to show that on the basis of `\csname`'s triggering of expansion you can use `\expandafter` for "tricking" LaTeX into expanding `\N` and `\V` as well:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.csv}
a, A, 100
b, B, 200
c, C, 300
d, D, 400
e, E, 500
f, F, 600
g, G, 700
h, H, 800
i, I, 900
\end{filecontents}


% Load database
\DTLloaddb[noheader]{\jobname}{\jobname.csv}

% Define macros
\DTLforeach{\jobname}{\Tag=Column1, \N=Column2, \V=Column3}{%
  \expandafter\def\csname\Tag\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{\N}%
  \expandafter\def\csname\Tag Value\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{\V}%
}%


\begin{enumerate}
\item \a, \aValue
\item \b, \bValue
\item \c, \cValue
\item \d, \dValue
\item \e, \eValue
\item \f, \fValue
\item \g, \gValue
\item \h, \hValue
\item \i, \iValue
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

**Issue 2:**

`\a`, `\b`, `\c`, `\d` and `\i` are already defined in the LaTeX 2ε-kernel.
The `\DTLforeach`-loop might override the already existing definitions.

Therefore I once more modified your example:

- Each command that is to be defined has the name-prefix `MY`.
- Instead of `\def` now `\newcommand*` is used. This will raise an error-message in case of overriding something already defined.
- The usefulness of the macro `\name` is shown:

  `\name\newcommand{macro}...` → `\newcommand\macro...`
  `\name\string{macro}` → `\string\macro`
  `\name\name\let{macroA}={macroB}` → `\name\let\macroA={macroB}` → `\let\macroA=\macroB`

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}
\csname @ifdefinable\endcsname\name{\long\def\name#1#{\romannumeral0\innername{#1}}}%
\newcommand\innername[2]{%
  \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{ #1}%
}%

\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.csv}
a, A, 100
b, B, 200
c, C, 300
d, D, 400
e, E, 500
f, F, 600
g, G, 700
h, H, 800
i, I, 900
\end{filecontents}

% Load database
\DTLloaddb[noheader]{\jobname}{\jobname.csv}

% Define macros
\DTLforeach{\jobname}{\Tag=Column1, \N=Column2, \V=Column3}{%
  \name\expandafter\newcommand\expandafter*\expandafter{MY\Tag}\expandafter{\N}%
  \name\expandafter\newcommand\expandafter*\expandafter{MY\Tag Value}\expandafter{\V}%
}%

\begin{enumerate}
\item \MYa, \MYaValue
\item \MYb, \MYbValue
\item \MYc, \MYcValue
\item \MYd, \MYdValue
\item \MYe, \MYeValue
\item \MYf, \MYfValue
\item \MYg, \MYgValue
\item \MYh, \MYhValue
\item \MYi, \MYiValue
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Besides this I can offer a macro `\ExtractKthArg` which extracts the K-th argument of a list of non-delimited arguments if a K-th argument exists in the list.

You can have `\DTLforeach` define for each row of the database a macro which expands to a list of non-delimited arguments denoting the entries in the columns with that row, and use `\ExtractKthArg` for retrieving the single elements/column-entries of the row:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Code for \ExtractKthArg
%%=============================================================================
%% Paraphernalia:
%%    \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo, \UD@PassFirstToSecond, 
%%    \UD@CheckWhetherNull,
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstBehindThirdToSecond[3]{#2{#3}{#1}}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}%
  \UD@secondoftwo}{\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Extract K-th inner undelimited argument:
%%
%% \ExtractKthArg{<integer K>}%
%%               {<list of non-delimited args>}%
%%               {<tokens in case K is not positive>}%
%%               {<tokens in case list has less than K args>}%
%% 
%% In case K is not positive:
%%   Does deliver <tokens in case K is not positive>.
%% In case K is positive but there is no K-th argument in <list of non-delimited args> : 
%%   Does deliver <tokens in case list has less than K args>.
%% In case there is a K-th argument in <list of non-delimited args> : 
%%   Does deliver that K-th argument with one level of braces removed.
%%
%% Due to \romannumeral0-expansion the result is delivered after two
%% expansion-steps/after two "hits" with \expandafter.
%%
%% Examples:
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{0}{ABCDE}{K not positive}{No Kth Element in list} yields: K not positive
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{3}{ABCDE}{K not positive}{No Kth Element in list} yields:  C
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{3}{AB{CD}E}{K not positive}{No Kth Element in list} yields:  CD
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{4}{{001}{002}{003}{004}{005}}{K not positive}{No Kth Element in list} yields: 004
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{6}{{001}{002}{003}}{K not positive}{No Kth Element in list} yields: No Kth Element in list
%% 
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\ExtractKthArg[1]{%
  % #1: <integer number K>
  \romannumeral0%
  \expandafter\UD@ExtractKthArgCheck
  \expandafter{\romannumeral\number\number#1 000}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractKthArgCheck[4]{%
  % #1: <Amount of letters "m" corresponding to number K>
  % #2: <list of non-delimited args>
  % #3: <tokens in case K is not positive>
  % #4: <tokens in case list has less than K args>
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{ #3}{%
    \expandafter\UD@ExtractKthArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}{#2}{#4}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractKthArgLoop[3]{%
  % #1: <remaining amount of letters "m">
  % #2: <(remaining) list of non-delimited args>
  % #3: <tokens in case list has less than K args>
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo#2{}.}{ #3%
  }{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{%
      \UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop{#2\UD@SelDOm}%
    }{%
      \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#2}%
      {\expandafter\UD@ExtractKthArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}}%
      {#3}%
    }%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm{}%
\long\def\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm#1#2\UD@SelDOm{{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop[1]{%
  % #1: <(remaining) list of non-delimited args>
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  {\UD@firstoftwo{\expandafter}{} \UD@secondoftwo{}#1}%
  {\expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm#1}}%
}%
%% End of code for \ExtractKthArg.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.csv}
a, A, 100
b, B, 200
c, C, 300
d, D, 400
e, E, 500
f, F, 600
g, G, 700
h, H, 800
i, I, 900
\end{filecontents}

% Load database
\DTLloaddb[noheader]{\jobname}{\jobname.csv}

\makeatletter
% Define macro for each row:
\DTLforeach{\jobname}{\Tag=Column1, \N=Column2, \V=Column3}{%
   \expandafter\@gobble\string{%
      \expandafter\UD@PassFirstBehindThirdToSecond\expandafter{\V}{%
        \expandafter\UD@PassFirstBehindThirdToSecond\expandafter{\N}{%
          \expandafter\UD@PassFirstBehindThirdToSecond\expandafter{\Tag}{%
            \UD@secondoftwo{}%
          }%
        }%
      }%
      {\expandafter\newcommand\csname Row\Tag%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endcsname
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\@gobble\string}}%
   }%
   %\expandafter\show\csname Row\Tag\endcsname
}%
\newcommand\GenericGetElementOfRow[4]{%
  % #1 = Entry in field "\Tag=Column 1" (, the primary key for rows)
  % #2 = Column-Number (beginning with 1)
  % #3 = <Tokens in case row is undefined>
  % #4 = <Tokens in case row is defined but does not have an element in column #2>
  \@ifundefined{Row#1}{%
    #3%
  }{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\csname Row#1\endcsname}%
    {\ExtractKthArg{#2}}%
    {}{#4}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\GetTagofRow[1]{%
  % #1 = Entry in field "\Tag=Column 1" (, the primary key for rows)
  \GenericGetElementOfRow{#1}{1}{%
    % Tokens in case row is undefined:
    \nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries??}%
  }{%
    % Tokens in case row defined but does not have K-th element:
    \nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries??}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\GetNofRow[1]{%
  % #1 = Entry in field "\Tag=Column 1" (, the primary key for rows)
  \GenericGetElementOfRow{#1}{2}{%
    % Tokens in case row is undefined:
    \nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries??}%
  }{%
    % Tokens in case row defined but does not have K-th element:
    \nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries??}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\GetVofRow[1]{%
  % #1 = Entry in field "\Tag=Column 1" (, the primary key for rows)
  \GenericGetElementOfRow{#1}{3}{%
    % Tokens in case row is undefined:
    \nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries??}%
  }{%
    % Tokens in case row defined but does not have K-th element:
    \nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries??}%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{itemize}
\item[\GetTagofRow{a}:] \GetNofRow{a}, \GetVofRow{a}
\item[\GetTagofRow{b}:] \GetNofRow{b}, \GetVofRow{b}
\item[\GetTagofRow{c}:] \GetNofRow{c}, \GetVofRow{c}
\item[\GetTagofRow{d}:] \GetNofRow{d}, \GetVofRow{d}
\item[\GetTagofRow{e}:] \GetNofRow{e}, \GetVofRow{e}
\item[\GetTagofRow{f}:] \GetNofRow{f}, \GetVofRow{f}
\item[\GetTagofRow{g}:] \GetNofRow{g}, \GetVofRow{g}
\item[\GetTagofRow{h}:] \GetNofRow{h}, \GetVofRow{h}
\item[\GetTagofRow{i}:] \GetNofRow{i}, \GetVofRow{i}
\item[\GetTagofRow{j}:] \GetNofRow{j}, \GetVofRow{j}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```